# writing a function in R that selects the a string based on the first instance of a letter and replaces the string

Tags: r, string, function

I have a data frame with several variables like this:

```
land_unit<-c("0.5ha", "hactares", "ha", "ha", "acre", "3ha", 
              "lima", "limas", "acre", "cunny", "6 cunnies")
```

I want to write a function that will tidy this data for me as i have many variables in my data frame with a similar format. I would like the function to replace each element based on the first letter that appears in the string. For example if the first letter to appear in the string is "h" I want the whole string replaced by "ha", if "l" then "lima", if "a" then "acre" and if "c" then "kani".

I have searched widely on this but cannot find an answer, however I am aware that there must be a relatively simple solution. Perhaps using regex?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the expected output based on the example?  If you have a string like `acre`, then would it be `acrecre`?

Comment: no it would just be "acre". so output would be something like  land_unit<-c("ha",   "ha",   "ha",   "ha",   "acre", "ha",   "lima", "lima", "acre", "kani", "kani")

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, may be this helps.  We use `gsubfn` to match zero or more characters that are not a letter (`[^A-Za-z]*`) from the start of the string (`^`) followed by a single letter captured as a group (`([a-z])`) followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace the capture group by a named key/value `list`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("^[^A-Za-z]*([a-z]).*", list(h = "ha", l="lima", a = "acre", c = "kani"), land_unit)
#[1] "ha"   "ha"   "ha"   "ha"   "acre" "ha"   "lima" "lima" "acre" "kani" "kani"
```

Comment: also occasionally there are other units that will not fit into those categories (acre,ha,lima,kani). is there some way to leave all others that dont match this list left as is?

Comment: @JoshVanVianen  My answer is based on the example you provided

Comment: your solution is perfect! would there be a simple `gsub` solution to the same?

Answer (score 1):

This should also work (with making the lookup table hard-coded and decoupling the data from code):

```
land_unit<-c("0.5ha", "hactares", "ha", "ha", "acre", "3ha", 
             "lima", "limas", "acre", "cunny", "6 cunnies")

library(stringr)
# define a lookup table, decouple the data
lookup_table <- data.frame(first.letter=c('h', 'l', 'a', 'c'), 
                           replace.str=c('ha', 'lima', 'acre', 'kani'), 
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
# extract the matches
matches <- match(str_match(land_unit, "[^[:alpha:]]*([:alpha:]).*")[,2] , lookup_table[,1]) 
# replace from lookup table
ifelse(!is.na(matches), lookup_table[matches,2], land_unit) 
# [1] "ha"   "ha"   "ha"   "ha"   "acre" "ha"   "lima" "lima" "acre" "kani" "kani"
```

Comment: i think your output is slightly different. `hactares`?

Comment: I haven't yet done! I'm waiting for him to rectify it @akrun